# Preventing low-skill physical access by creating fake desktop environment

Tags: linux, physical-access

How can I create a fake desktop environment and file system, that automatically starts as default when booting up, and may be exited out of by doing a specific action? (Like a keystroke) to prevent physical access?

Comment: Create a dual boot system. Make the fake system the default system which will boot. Run some script which will detect certain key strokes and then powers off the machine.

Comment: @secfren This seems to do the trick. However, the actual system is visible in the file system, what can I do about that?

Comment: Encrypt it. If you don't use LUKS but plain dm-crypt you can hide that to a certain extend too. iirc you can also allow only certain users (like root) to be able to look at disk info. It all depends on what kind of access the attacker has and how close he wants to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it backwards. I'd have a full system that starts on bootup that can be accessed by anyone but your protected system runs as a virtual machine or subsystem. You can protect, encrypt, and hide the encrypted VM as you see fit.

Or, run the protected system off of a removable drive.

Answer (score 1):

The mitigations to physical access are:

- Physical security
- User access control (Passwords/smart cards/etc)
- Hard drive encryption

Obfuscation will never replace any of these, no matter how tempting it may seem.  I guess one could run grub-reboot after booting into a fake image but I would not use this to replace any of the former security layers.

Comment: @AaravPrasad if an attacker is looking for something, they probably wont stop at "boy, gee, yea, looks like their desktop is clean."  They'll probably continue with the lead pipe until they get what they are looking for.  I guess grub-reboot could get you kinda there.  Boot to decoy by default, grub-reboot to the real image.  But that will only fool the most uneducated of attackers.

Comment: Who has your password? Implementing some nerdy plausible deniability utopia is probably not going to pan out the way you hope and a blanket approach is unlikely to work, as per the lead pipe comment from @foreverska

Comment: @wireghoul The scenario I am proposing is good enough for school IT searching our own personal laptops